# No longer able to issue pull request after branch name change to master

Tags: git, github

I have a forked repo. In it I had a master branch and a dev branch and feature branches. As the forked repo is basically a development repo it became clear that the dev branch was not useful and I ended up making lots of conflict errors between the dev and the master branch. So I decided to get rid of the dev branch

As I have a few Feature branches I decided to merge dev and the master branch so everything was synced. I then deleted the master branch and renamed the dev branch as master.

Now when I try to issue a pull request on github to the original repo I am presented with the green button 'Create pull request' but nothing happens.

Is this because I have renamed a branch? How can I rectify this issue?

Comment: Generally PRs are created against default branch. Go to settings and check whether default branch is still master branch ? If not, then update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficult to exactly tell from what you describe here, but if your history has been rewritten (depending on *how* you "synced" `dev` and `master`), your remote has to be updated to the new history, which it will (by design) refuse to do unless you explicitly specify it. That's what `--force` is for.

In this case if I got it right you're the sole developer*, so you don't have to bother with problems down the line, namely conflicting with coworkers' history of `master`. So just

```
git push --force origin master
```

* *(if it's not the case, however, comment and I'll update)*